# Can AngularJS templates use TypeScript for type-safety?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Assuming an Angular 1.6 app using best practices (components/bind-to-controller where possible), can we harness the power of TypeScript in templates?

For example if we have some template code

```
<div>{{$ctrl.children[0].name}}</div>
```

& we know the type of the controller ($ctrl) - can we have TypeScript give us an error if

- 'children' does not exist on $ctrl
- 'children' is not an array
- the items in 'children' do not have a property 'name' (etc)?

Code completion in VS Code would be nice too.

I've seen the issues below:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6508
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5151

However it's difficult to conclude from that where things are at (especially in the AngularJS 1.x world).

Comment: If it's relevant, Webpack (2) is being used to manage bundling.

Comment: angular 2 has something like this when compiling ahead of time. for angularjs though the templates are not being compiled at buildtime so they never get to pass trough such a check.

Comment: @toskv - I'm asking whether there is a way to compile/check AngularJS templates at build time.

Comment: I got that. And the answer is no because angularjs templates are not compiled. they only get interpreted at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you could start writing Angular 2 components and then downgrade them to AngularJS using `@angular/upgrade/static::downgradeComponent` [downgradeComponent](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeComponent)

Answer (score 1):

No.

AngularJs templates are interpreted at runtime, there is no compilation step for them where this check could happen.

Comment: Wondering if there might be external tooling or a compiler extension point (e.g. VS Code plugin) that parses & validates the templates (I think it's clear that this functionality isn't built into the TS compiler - it doesn't belong there). Will leave the question open for a bit longer and if no further answers will accept yours :)